# R Colors not Consistent - col=1, col="white", and col="#FFFFFF"

Tags: r, colors

I googled color specification in R and looked at several pages. They all explain the same technique for specifying a background color in R with the following command

```
par(bg = "white")
```

That works. They also explain other ways to specify the same thing. For example `col = 1`, `col = "white"`, and `col = "#FFFFFF"` are equivalent. Except it's not quite working for me.

```
par(bg=1)
```

If I enter the command directly above I get a black background. Not white. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where does it say `col=1` is `"white"`? `1` will be interpreted as `palette()[1]` which is `"black"` by default. As per `?par` - "*Colors can also be specified by giving an index into a small table of colors, the ‘palette’*"

Comment: It would help if you would cite your sources so we can see where you are getting this information. Is it in the official R documentation?

Comment: `colors()[1]` is "white". Is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: [Source](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html)

About halfway down there is a COLORS heading. Under this section there is the explanation that "You can specify colors in R by index, name, hexadecimal, or RGB. For example col=1, col="white", and col="#FFFFFF" are equivalent."

Comment: contact the author (scroll to bottom of linked page) and ask them to fix the typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to specify background color by R color index is as follows:

```
par(bg = colors()[1])
```